# Xcode 8 cannot run on physical device without membership

Tags: ios, xcode

I used to have a membership to the Apple Developer Program (99$/year), but a couple of years ago I stopped renewing since I didn't have time to develop. 
Now I got back playing with iOS and Xcode but I cannot have my apps running on a physical device (ps I do not have the membership now) 
Basically Xcode outputs this

```
Unable to add device 'iPhone ***' because the team has 
already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: ***" 
doesn't include the currently selected device "iPhone ***".
```

Actually it looks like my Xcode is still tied to my old account. I tried to manage my account looking for the devices but had no luck, the only meaningful thing I can do on at https://developer.apple.com/account/ is to renew my membership.

Anyone knows how can I solve this issue without the need to create a new Apple ID?

Comment: Just add a new Development Team in your project settings.

Comment: you may need to renew your membership if you want to use _real_ devices for testing, otherwise you can use the simulator any time without live membership, but I would not rely on that environment too much.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup should I create a new Apple ID to do that?

Comment: @holex from Xcode 7 (I think) you have the possibility to test your apps on a real device without membership, I need to use the camera that is why I cannot play with the simulator :-)

Comment: Yes, then it allow you a certain amount of bundle IDs and devices tied to the account.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup ok thank you. Anyway I still do not understand why that happens with my account? I mean, I haven't done anything since my licence expired so I should be in condition to test apps as anyone else without membership :-(

Comment: No.  When you have an account that is not a paid membership, it only allows so many bundle ids and devices registered before you have to pay.  Usually what people do is just keep making new accounts.

Comment: Wow... I had to check that it wasn't me who wrote this question. I have exactly the same story and am also looking for a solution that won't cost me an absurd $100.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new apple id or use a different account. In Xcode, go to preferences > accounts > +. In your project general settings, go to Signing > Team and select your new account from the dropdown list. Then try to run from your device and you should be able to go through a couple of prompts to get it running just as if you were a new developer. Silly workaround.

I had the same problem and have a support ticket in with Apple to see if there's a better solution.